# How to append XML string to DOMDocument without namespaces

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I'm using PHP and have to build a `SOAP` (**1.1**, **Document/Literal**) request that contains a XML message inside `soap:Body` tag.

> My first issue is that I'd never used this "protocol" before.

My XML message is quite complex so I'm using `SimpleXMLElement` class to build it separately. To compose the `SOAP` message, I have two XML strings:

1- The `SOAP` structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header></soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>...</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

2- My Custom XML String

```
<eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v2_2_02" grupo="1">
  <envioLoteEventos>
    <ideEmpregador tpInsc="1" nrInsc="0000000012"/>
    <ideTransmissor tpInsc="1" nrInsc="0000000012"/>
    <eventos>
      <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInfoEmpregador/v2_2_02">
        <evtInfoEmpregador Id="8515">...</evtInfoEmpregador>
      </eSocial>
    </eventos> 
  </envioLoteEventos>
</eSocial>
```

- **What I need:** The second string inside `soap:Body` tag exactly as it is.
- **What I get:** The second string inside `soap:Body` with a bunch of namespaces automatically added by `DOMDocument`.

The algorithm (not full code) that I'm using:

```
$soapBodyElement = new SimpleXMLElement($soapBodyString);
$customMessageElement = new SimpleXMLElement($customMessageString);
// Some operations...
$domParent = dom_import_simplexml($soapBodyElement);
$domChild = dom_import_simplexml($customMessageElement);
$domDocument = $domParent->ownerDocument->importNode($domChild, true);
$domParent->appendChild($domDocument);

echo $domParent->ownerDocument->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<soap:Envelope 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v2_2_02" xmlns:default="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInfoEmpregador/v2_2_02" xmlns:default1="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" grupo="1">
      <envioLoteEventos>
        <ideEmpregador tpInsc="1" nrInsc="0000000012"/>
        <ideTransmissor tpInsc="1" nrInsc="0000000012"/>
        <eventos>
          <default:eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInfoEmpregador/v2_2_02">
            <default:evtInfoEmpregador Id="2550">...</default:evtInfoEmpregador>
          </default:eSocial>
        </eventos>
      </envioLoteEventos>
    </eSocial>     
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Honestly, I don't know why this `default` prefixes (namespaces?) were added.

How can I append two XML strings without this automatic behavior?

Comment: Have you tried to create the XML file from scratch with DOMDocument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Marshal XML Serializer](https://github.com/Kingson-de/marshal-xml-serializer) which is much easier to use then DOMDocument and SimpleXML.

Then you could do the following:

**SoapEnvelopeMapper.php**

```
use KingsonDe\Marshal\AbstractXmlMapper;

class SoapEnvelopeMapper extends AbstractXmlMapper {

    /**
     * @var AbstractXmlMapper
     */
    private $messageMapper;

    public function __construct(AbstractXmlMapper $messageMapper) {
        $this->messageMapper = $messageMapper;
    }

    public function map($data) {
        return [
            'soap:Envelope' => [
                $this->attributes() => [
                    'xmlns:xsi'  => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
                    'xmlns:xsd'  => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
                    'xmlns:soap' => 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope',
                ],
                'soap:Header' => null,
                'soap:Body' => $this->item($this->messageMapper, $data),
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

**SoapMessageMapper.php**

```
use KingsonDe\Marshal\AbstractXmlMapper;

class SoapMessageMapper extends AbstractXmlMapper {

    public function map($data) {
        return [
            'eSocial' => [
                $this->attributes() => [
                    'xmlns'          => 'http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v2_2_02',
                    'xmlns:default'  => 'http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInfoEmpregador/v2_2_02',
                    'xmlns:default1' => 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#',
                    'grupo'          => 1,
                ],
                'envioLoteEventos' => [
                    'ideEmpregador' => [
                        $this->attributes() => [
                            'tpInsc' => 1,
                            'nrInsc' => '0000000012',
                        ],
                    ],
                    'ideTransmissor' => [
                        $this->attributes() => [
                            'tpInsc' => 1,
                            'nrInsc' => '0000000012',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'eventos' => [
                    'eSocial' => [
                        $this->attributes() => [
                            'xmlns' => 'http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInfoEmpregador/v2_2_02',
                        ],
                        'evtInfoEmpregador' => [
                            $this->attributes() => [
                                'Id' => 2550,
                            ],
                            $this->data() => '...',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

**SoapResponse.php**

```
$data = new \stdClass();

$messageMapper  = new SoapMessageMapper();
$envelopeMapper = new SoapEnvelopeMapper($messageMapper);

$xml = MarshalXml::serializeItem($envelopeMapper, $data);
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this project and created my own library (using `SimpleXMLElement` under the hoods) to convert data structures to XML strings and it works exactly like that. The issue with my lib is that it adds a child element and then after add his relative attributes, winch gives me an error message by `SimpleXMLElement` because of creation of "soap:Envelope" element without namespaces (which is added in the next line). Anyway, I will take a look at marshal-xml-serializer.

Comment: The project is brand new :) It uses `DOMDocument` so it does not run into the limitations of `SimpleXML`. Hope you like it. Any comments, suggestions are welcome!